# Query MongoDB by nested document and show specific variable only

Tags: mongodb

I have document with contained nested array like below:

1. `{"data": [{"Measure": "Temperature","value" : 10},{"Measure": "Humidity","value" : 10}],"date" : ISODate("2017-11-22T00:30:48.257Z")}`
2. `{"data": [{"Measure": "Temperature","value" : 15},{"Measure": "Humidity","value" : 15}],"date" : ISODate("2017-11-22T00:31:23.215Z")}`

I have done `db.collection.find({'data.Measure':'Temperature'}, {'data.$':1, 'date':1})` and result shows:

```
[{
    "data" : [{
            "Measure": "Temperature",
            "value" : 10
    }],
        "date" : ISODate("2017-11-22T00:30:48.257Z")
},{
    "data" : [{
            "Measure": "Temperature",
            "value" : 15
        }],
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-22T00:31:23.215Z")
}]
```

actually, I would like to queries `Measure:Temperature` as result:

```
[{
    "Measure": "Temperature",
    "value" : 5,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-22T00:30:48.257Z")
}, {
    "Measure": "Temperature",
    "value" : 15,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-22T00:31:23.215Z")
}]
```

Can I queries and get result like this?

Comment: Use aggregation to transform the result. First `$unwind` `Data` followed by `$match` on `Meaure` and `$group` to put back the matching document into array of documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation pipeline to get the mentioned result. To get the result you have to use aggregation with $unwind then $match the condition and then after project the result. Please read documention of MongoDb [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/index.html) and [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/index.html)

I have prepare the query for you:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
{$unwind: '$data'},
{$match:{'data.Measure':'Temperature'}},
{$project:  {
    _id:0,
    "Measure" : "$data.Measure",
    "value" : "$data.value",
    "date" : '$date'

 }}).toArray();
```